# Solving Equations in Perl

Tags: perl, math, binary-search, equation, equation-solving

How should I solve my equations in Perl?

I know binary search is one solution (and perhaps pretty fast for my equations) but I would like to know if there is a ready to use solutions such as math packages or libraries so that I can use them instead of implementing my own solver?

**NOTE:**

- This is, find `x` for a given `y`.
- The functions are strictly increasing
- The equations usually look like: `y = a + b*sqrt(x) + b*x` or  `y = sqrt(a*(x-b)**2*(x-c)/(x-d))`
- Please don't complain that "this is off topic" or "you should ask this in http://math.stackexchange.com". I want to see this problem from the programming point of view, particularly in **Perl**!

Comment: Any chance you could combine a function with `eval` and compute most such equations directly?  Or when you say "solve" are you meaning in the mathematical sense, such as "find the zeroes of the quadratic `y=x^2+3x-7`"?

Comment: Find `x` for a given `y`. Read the question carefully.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using libraries? There's [Math::LP](http://search.cpan.org/~wimv/Math-LP-0.03/lib/Math/LP.pm), for instance.

See the [Perl and Math](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=284324) tutorial from PerlMonks for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Search for symbolic math on MetaCPAN.  Lots of interesting looking options.
https://metacpan.org/search?q=symbolic+math